# Nginx Configuration files with error

Tags: wordpress, nginx, configuration

I am new nginx configuration and I like to know what's wrong with my "code" .

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 65536;
 # use epoll;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##
 
 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 65;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
 server_tokens off;
 client_max_body_size 180M;



 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 # server_name_in_redirect off;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;

 ##
 # SSL Settings
 ##

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
# # See sample authentication script at:
# # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
# # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
# # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
# # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:110;
#  protocol   pop3;
#  proxy      on;
# }
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:143;
#  protocol   imap;
#  proxy      on;
# }
#}
```

My NGINX host conf

```html
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

 # SSL configuration
 #
 # listen 443 ssl default_server;
 # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
 #
 # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
 # Don't use them in a production server!
 #
 # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

 root /var/www/html;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
 index index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 server_name 37.187.29.28;
 
 location / {
  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }
 
 location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;
}




 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
 # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 try_files $uri =404;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 include fastcgi_params;
 # # With php5-cgi alone:
 # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 # # With php5-fpm:
 # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 #location ~ /\.ht {
 # deny all;
 #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
# listen 80;
# listen [::]:80;
#
# server_name example.com;
#
# root /var/www/example.com;
# index index.html;
#
# location / {
#  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
# }
#}
```

and i have allready an error for my host conf :

```html
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default test failed
```

The website is a Wordpress.

It has many plugin and so many requests .

Help me !

Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: Are you just testing the `default` file or the `nginx.conf` file? Because the file `default` is not a complete `nginx` configuration file, it is included into the main `nginx.conf` file on the last line of your `http` block.

Comment: i have configured a new one site-available conf and same problem with server : 
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/terravictoria:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/terravictoria test failed

Comment: and now i have this error : 504 Gateway Time-out

 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream